# Lifetime for passed-in function that is then executed in a thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, channel, lifetime

I'm trying to build a simple pipeline-like functionality that executes each stage of the pipeline is separate threads and glues them all together with channel passing.

```
Pipe::source(buffer)
     .pipe(|input, output| {...})
     .pipe(|input, output| {...})
     .sink(writer)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the function signature for the `pipe()` function. Here's my code:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::io::{ChanReader,ChanWriter};
use std::thread::Thread;

struct Pipe {
    incoming: ChanReader
}

impl Pipe {
    fn source(source: &mut Buffer) -> Pipe {
        let (tx, rx) = channel();
        let reader = ChanReader::new(rx);
        let mut writer = ChanWriter::new(tx);

        loop {
            match source.read_char() {
                Ok(c) => writer.write_char(c),
                Err(_) => break
            };
        };

        Pipe { incoming: reader }
    }

    fn sink(&mut self, sink: &mut Writer) {
        loop {
            match self.incoming.read_char() {
                Ok(c) => sink.write_char(c),
                Err(_) => break
            };
        };
    }

    fn pipe(&self, transform: Box<Fn(&mut ChanReader, &mut ChanWriter)+Send>) -> Pipe {
        let (tx, rx) = channel();
        let reader = ChanReader::new(rx);
        let mut writer = ChanWriter::new(tx);

        Thread::spawn(move || {
            transform(&self.incoming, &writer);
        });

        Pipe { incoming: reader }
    }
}
```

And the compiler error:

```
src/lib.rs:39:28: 41:10 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
src/lib.rs:40             transform(&self.incoming, &writer);
src/lib.rs:41         });
src/lib.rs:39:9: 39:22 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 39:8...
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:39:9: 39:22 note: ...so that the declared lifetime parameter bounds are satisfied
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:39:9: 41:11 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 39:8...
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
src/lib.rs:40             transform(&self.incoming, &writer);
src/lib.rs:41         });
src/lib.rs:39:28: 41:10 note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
src/lib.rs:40             transform(&self.incoming, &writer);
src/lib.rs:41         });
src/lib.rs:39:9: 39:22 error: declared lifetime bound not satisfied
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:34:87: 44:6 note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 34:86
src/lib.rs:34     fn pipe(&self, transform: Box<Fn(&mut ChanReader, &mut ChanWriter)+Send>) -> Pipe {
src/lib.rs:35         let (tx, rx) = channel();
src/lib.rs:36         let reader = ChanReader::new(rx);
src/lib.rs:37         let mut writer = ChanWriter::new(tx);
src/lib.rs:38
src/lib.rs:39         Thread::spawn(move || {
              ...
note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Could not compile `pipes`.
```

I am using `1.0.0-dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread::spawn` requires the function that is given to it to be `'static`; the closure must thus consume all things that come into it. You have gone taking a reference to `self.incoming`—a non-static reference. This won’t work; you must move the reader into it. The way to do this is probably to be consuming `self` in the method `pipe` rather than taking it by reference:

```
fn pipe<F: FnOnce(&mut ChanReader, &mut ChanWriter) + Send>(mut self, transform: F) -> Pipe {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    let reader = ChanReader::new(rx);
    let mut writer = ChanWriter::new(tx);

    Thread::spawn(move || {
        transform(&mut self.incoming, &mut writer);
    });

    Pipe { incoming: reader }
}
```

Now, `self` and `writer` are moved into the spawned thread and everything is dandy.

(For good measure I unboxed your closure as there’s no reason for it to be boxed and changed it to `FnOnce` for maximal expressiveness.)

Comment: Awesome. That made the compiler happy. The `Box` was my final attempt at saying "give me all the ownership, dangit". Looks like the `mut` directives were what I was missing in my arguments